# Excluding IP from Google Analytics - Why is this not a valid regular expression?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to exclude a range of IP addresses from Google Analytics. But it complains that my regular expression is invalid:

Range of addresses example: `192.168.0.130 to 192.168.0.135`

My regular expression: `192\.168\.0\.[130-135]`

What's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions is about characters, regex doesn't know that `130-135` is a range between numbers. It sees it as mere characters. So what you need to do is the following:

`192\.168\.0\.13[0-5]`

Let's explain it:

- `192\.168\.0\.13` will match `192.168.0.13`
- `[0-5]` will match a range between `0` and `5`

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it now, but but what if the range part is 128-135? How would that look? Then it's not as simple as 13[0-5] and I guess I need some form of conditions then. Will it be something like: 194\.236\.9\.(12[8-9]|13[0-5]) ?